# SQL login fail at table creation

Tags: sql, vb.net, authentication

My code creates a database then creates tables for the database. Sometimes when I run the code it works. Other times, the database is created, but when it attempts to create the tables an exception is thrown: Login failed for user ''

Strangely though, it sometimes does work and creates the tables, then other times it throws this error, without changing any code.

Edit: Also The code for table creation always works when I have it as a separate button after the database is created, Even though it has problems when I place it right after the database creation.

I am using integrated security. If anyone could let me know why this problem is happening and how I can fix it that would be appreciated.

Database Creation code:

```vb
Dim str As String
    '"Data Source=(Local)\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Integrated Security=True"
    Dim myConn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Server=(local)\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True;database=master")

    str = "Create Database TestDB"
    Dim myCommand As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(str, myConn)

    Try
        myConn.Open()
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Dim result1 As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Database is created successfully",
                    "MyProgram", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                     MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        If result1 = DialogResult.OK Then
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
    Finally
        If (myConn.State = ConnectionState.Open) Then
            myConn.Close()
        End If
        Me.Close()
    End Try
```

Table creation code:

```vb
Try
            Dim con As New SqlConnection
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
            con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(Local)\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Integrated Security=True"
            con.Open()
            cmd.Connection = con
            cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE parts" + "(partID nvarchar(50), description nvarchar(50), color nvarchar(50))"
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE stockNew" + "(stockID1 nvarchar(50), stockID2 nvarchar(50), stockID3 nvarchar(50))"
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE stockUsed" + "(stockID1 nvarchar(50), stockID2 nvarchar(50), stockID3 nvarchar(50))"
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE activationCode" + "(blah nvarchar(50))"
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MessageBox.Show("Tables have been created successfully", "MyProgram", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
        End Try
```

Comment: I added another strange occurrence:
The code for table creation always works when I have it as a separate button after the database is created, Even though it has problems when I place it right after the database creation.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a pooling issue.  Your initial catalog may not be set and as a result you may be trying to create these tables in Master.  Try fully qualified table names and see it it fixes the issues.  **CREATE TABLE TestDB.dbo.stockUsed... etc. etc.**

Comment: It did not work, I still have the exception, cannot open database, login failed for user